# Como verificar o formato e tipo de um arquivo de texto?

Tags: jquery, file-upload

Eu tenho um *input file* no qual eu limitei para que só aceite arquivo cujo o formato seja um arquivo de texto, com extensão `.txt`.

Usei o atributo `accept` para isso, veja:

```
accept=".txt"
```

Entretanto, eu gostaria de saber se é possível verificar usando jQuery, o formato e o tipo do arquivo no caso do atributo `accept` falhar?

---

## Mcve

Exemplo de ilustração:

```js
function verificarArquivoTexto(arq)
{

}

$(
 function ()
  {
   $('input:file').change(
     function(e)
      {
       var arq = $(this).val().split('\\').pop();
        $('.arquivo').html(arq);
      }
    );
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="upload" type="file" name="file-upload" accept=".txt">
<div class="arquivo">

</div>
```

Comment: Eu deixaria de lado verificar mimetype front-end e focaria mais na extensão do arquivo e  no peso. Mesmo que fosse tentado enviar um arquivo .txt que não seja .txt, pode fazer essa verificação no servidor. O front-end tem mais a função de evitar requisições desnecessárias ao servidor, mas pode ser alterado e uma % muito baixa de clientes vai perder tempo com isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não necessariamente com jQuery, mas sim com a API `File` nativa do JavaScript, assim por exemplo:

```
$('input:file').change(function (e) {
    console.log("Tipo:", this.files[0].type);
});
```

Se for upload de multiplos arquivos

```
$('input:file').change(function (e) {
    for (var i = 0, j = files.length; i < j; i++) {
        console.log("Tipo:", this.files[i].type);
    }
});
```

Exemplo:

```js
    $('input:file').change(function (e) {
        console.log("Campo: ", this.name);
        console.log("Tipo: ", this.files[0].type);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" name="arquivo1">
<input type="file" name="arquivo2">
```

Comment: Selecionei um arquivo .mp4 com extensão .txt e validou como .txt.

Comment: @dvd pra resolver isto só checando no back-end com php ou outra linguagem através do "MAGIC" (se o sistema operacional tiver suporte para o MAGIC), no geral o problema é implementação dos navegadores que é assim mesmo, funciona por "dedução".

Comment: Você não pode carregar o arquivo no browser? Tipo, o próprio JS consumir o arquivo a ser carregado?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado ele pode sim ler o conteúdo do arquivo, basta utilizar a API `FileReader`, mas a questão é se é viável, principalmente com "arquivos grandes".

Comment: @ValdeirPsr números mágicos normalmente estão nos primeiros 100 bytes do arquivo. Então seria passar esse octeto para um reconhecedor de números mágicos... (ok, agora só falta o reconhecedor xD)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o `this` usado para acessar a propriedade `files` faz referência ao `'input:file'`?

Comment: @gato sim, o jQuery exclusivamente usa o `.apply` para mudar o contexto das funções e eventos proprios, fazendo ser possivel se referir ao elemento DOM especifico, ou seja `this` irá equivaler ao `<input>` que disparou o change ;)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado é bem complexo, não só pelo consumo mas pela possibilidade de criar um MAGIC proprio para uma aplicação front-end, é possivel mas não existe nada pronto e eu teria que fazer tudo do zero, talvez no futuro eu crie algo no github e compartilhe. Adicionei um exemplo na resposta com jQuery para entender.

Answer (score 3):

Sim, é possível. Basta capturar os valores do atributo `input.files`, ele vai te retornar um array de File e depois é só verificar.

```js
const inputUpload = document.querySelector("#upload");

inputUpload.addEventListener("change", () => {
  
  for (let i = 0; i < inputUpload.files.length; i++) {
    if ( 
      inputUpload.files[i].name.match(/\.txt$/) && //Verifica se o nome do arquivo termina com .txt
      inputUpload.files[i].type == "text/plain" //Verifica o mimetype do arquivo
    ) {
      console.log( inputUpload.files[i].name + " é um txt" );
    } else {
      console.log( inputUpload.files[i].name +  "não é um txt" );
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="upload" type="file" name="file-upload" multiple >
```

Comment: Selecionei um arquivo .mp4 com extensão .txt e validou como .txt.

Comment: @dvd Conforme a documentação, isso acontece pois o Js não ler o `bytestream` do arquivo. Ele pega esse mimetype através da extensão do arquivo. (Algo semelhante ao método`MimeTypeMap.getMimeTypeFromExtension` do Android. Para uma precisão maior é necessário utilizar o back-end.

Comment: Só um adendo: Ele pode até utilizar a API FileReader para ler o conteúdo do arquivo via JS, mas não sei se vale a pena. Principalmente para grandes arquivos.