# Como permitir apenas formato personalizado em input?

Tags: html

Eu to fazendo um input com tipos personalizados e ele ainda continua exibindo "all files" e gostaria de removê-lo

```html
<input type="file" name="file" accept=".xls"  />
```

É possível fazer isso?

Comment: Pra ter certeza fui atrás de um link, mas não é possível remover esta opção (e como comentado, não é necessário) https://stackoverflow.com/a/24115254/4551469

Comment: Não é possível, mas você pode validar a extensão no lado do cliente e o mimetype no servidor. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/271946/99718

Comment: Vou fazer essa validaçao no cliente mesmo

Comment: Lembrando que o tipo de arquivo deve ser validado no back-end, caso contrário seria um erro de segurança e permitiria invasões.